# require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/SimplePie/Net/IPv4.php' ); Error on WP site

Tags: wordpress

I am getting this error on my WP site 
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/SimplePie/Net/IPv4.php' );

I search for this on Google but finds nothing. Please help me to solve with this. 
Here is link to website 
[Website link](http://silverdaleridge.com.au/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually that line of code is inserted into wp-settings.php in your wordpress core.
It's a backdoor virus.

Just go to wp-settings.php on line 21 and comment it.

I suggest getting your website scanned.

Comment: Scanned with what tool?

Comment: I usually use Wordfence ( free version ) to scan the website, usually  helps me find all the differences between my files and the default core files of wordpress. Plus can help you find other infected files